# Why do I get an error when trying to add an SNS trigger to my AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I'm trying to setup an AWS Lambda function that gets triggered when a CloudWatch alarm sends a message to an SNS topic. I'm following along in this guide:

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/generate-slack-notifications-for-aws-cloudwatch-alarms-e46b68540133

I'm stuck at step 6 at the point where it says to add the trigger to the function. I select my SNS topic as the trigger but when I hit Add it gives me the following error:

> An error occurred when creating the trigger: Invalid parameter:
> Invalid protocol type: lambda (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400;
> Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID:
> 343350ee-b514-5c7c-8180-08fe5fd643ec; Proxy: null)

[image]

Does anybody know what that error means and what I can do about it?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure Lambda supports integration with SNS FIFO topics yet. It took them a while to add support for SQS FIFO queues when that feature was released. Looking at the SNS FIFO announcement, it looks like they are doing SNS FIFO -> SQS FIFO -> Lambda. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/introducing-amazon-sns-fifo-first-in-first-out-pub-sub-messaging/

Comment: @MarkB is correct.

Comment: Thanks both! I changed the SNS topic to standard and it worked.

Comment: Doesn't support email with FIFO either apparently.

Answer (score 37):

I ran into this problem recently...

As of now, Lambda only supports Standard SNS topics.

You will need to change your SNS topic from FIFO to Standard.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks DanielWsk, looks like fifo only works with SQS. It was there but didn't see it.

[image]